# Can I fix warning C4570 generated by generic delegate declaration?

Tags: generics, delegates, c++-cx

The simple declaration of a generic delegate in C++/CX seems to generate a warning.  Example:

```
generic<typename T>
delegate void DoStuff();
```

generates the following on VS2012 Update 2:

```
warning C4570: 'DoStuff' : is not explicitly declared as abstract but has abstract functions
```

It doesn't matter if I change the delegate to return type `T` or take type `T` as a parameter or anything.  The only thing I've found that fixes the warning is to make the delegate non-generic.

As far as I'm aware it makes no sense to declare a delegate as abstract.  The docs say nothing about doing so.  When I tried anyway, I was greeted with the expected errors.  If the generic delegate somehow does have abstract functions, then it must be an implementation detail of C++/CX, which I obviously can't do anything about.

Am I just totally missing something basic?